# Mysql wrong time field in query

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, spring-data, raspbian

**Briefing:**
I'm working with Spring Boot, spring data and a dockerized mySQL database(community version).

- I have 2 instances of the database, one in a Raspberry Pi(Raspbian) and another in my pc (Ubuntu).
- The table i'm querying has a "time" field -> '10:00:00'
- I'm using the default findAll() method from JpaRepository.
- Ubuntu is in LMT time, set to my zone. Raspbian has GMT or UTC options, also set to my zone(+1).

**TL;DR;**

**Problem**:
Time field in bbdd table is 10:00:00 in both databases

- I query the database in my pc, it returns 10:00:00.
- I query the database in the pi, it returns 11:00:00.

Makes no sense to me.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is strange. Are you sure the column is a `TIME` column? The `TIME` data type doesn't have a time zone attached to it, so if you store 10:00:00 this is just 10:00:00, no matter the settings or the location of writing and reading. What you experience sounds more like an issue with a `TIMESTAMP` column. But well, maybe it's really your framework reading more into a `TIME` then there is :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing the same OS in both machines (ubuntu & ubuntu server). Raspbian had something messed up with timezones.